# Can the 1st generation Grubbs Catalyst be used for ring closing metathesis on non-terminal alkenes?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reactivity

I'm wondering if the 1<sup>st</sup> generation Grubbs catalyst can be used to do ring closing metathesis on a non-terminal alkene.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it appears that that ring closing metathesis of non-terminal alkenes has been performed using the [1st generation Grubbs catalyst](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/579726?lang=en&region=US) several times:

- [Asymmetric syntheses of enantiopure C(5)-substituted transpentacins
  via diastereoselective Ireland–Claisen rearrangements](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/C3CC43250E)
- [Stereoselective Synthesis of Deuterium-Labeled (2S)-Cyclohexenyl
  Alanines, Biosynthetic Intermediates of Cinnabaramide](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ol3029548)
- [Ru-catalyzed metathesis of octadienylether xyloside](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.catcom.2007.12.004) [Synthesis
  of (−)-Agelastatin A by [3.3] Sigmatropic Rearrangement of Allyl
  Cyanate](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ol0709735)
- [A chiral auxiliary cleavable by ring-closing alkene
  metathesis — Efficient synthesis of chiral nonracemic
  cycloalkenes](http://dx.doi.org/10.1139/v06-095)
- [Conversion of chiral unsaturated cyanohydrins into
  chiral carba- and heterocycles via ring-closing metathesis](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.tet.2004.07.103)
- [Total Synthesis of Pancratistatin Relying on the [3,3]-Sigmatropic
  Rearrangement](http://doi.dx.org/10.1021/jo035371n)
- [Stereoselective Chelate-Controlled Addition of Grignard Reagents to Unsaturated Medium-Ring Heterocycles](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/jo981745e)